# Table is not returning values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to print out my database into a table, but it isn't working properly.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$title = 'Adminpaneel | Gemeente Loket Den Haag';
require 'header.php';
require 'connect.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM aanvraag";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
?>

<table border="2" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Voornaam</th>
          <th>Achternaam</th>
          <th>email</th>
          <th>datum</th>
          <th>adres</th>
          <td>huisnummer</td>
          <td>Postcode</td>
          <td>Woonplaats</td>
          <td>Product</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <?php
          while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ ?>

            <tr>
               <td> <php echo $row['voornaam']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['achternaam']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['datum']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['adres']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['huisnr']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['postcode']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['woonplaats']; ?> </td>
               <td> <php echo $row['product']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<?php
require 'footer.aanvragen.php';
?>
```

The rows are created but the database values are missing. What seems to be the issue?

This is the table structure:

[image]

Comment: We will need to see your table design for this.

Comment: check the column names (maybe provide us the database schema for aanvraag table)

Comment: `<?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?>` and same for others i.e. `?` after the first `<`

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code for the html table:

```
<?php
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ ?>

        <tr>
          <td> <?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $row['achternaam']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $row['datum']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $row['adres']; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $row['huisnr']; ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $row['postcode']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $row['woonplaats']; ?> </td>
           <td> <?php echo $row['product']; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

as suggested by Abhik Chakraborty

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that I didn't put a ? before php. that was the problem thanks! (<?php

Answer (score 0):

```
<td> <php echo $row['voornaam']; ?> </td>
```

One line of the output (but it is the same for all the lines):
PHP needs to start with

So the solution will be:

```
<td><?php echo $row['voornaam']; ?> </td>
```

But for all the rows...

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that I didn't put a ? before php. that was the problem thanks! (<?php